Code folding not working for C files in CLion
TL;DR: only 1 of my C files is having working folding.
Hello,
I'm using CLion to write C code, but the code folding doesn't work for C files, altough it works well for markdown files.
Functions nor conditions are getting folded in most of my files.

The str.c file is the only one that has working foldings (see screenshot). In the other ones, I don't even see the folding arrows.

The str.c has a little blue chip on it's icon, not the other files. str.c is also the only file where i have the arrows to switch from function declaration and definition.
How can I make code folding work in other files ? (and linking with the header file too if possible)
Here is a screenshot of my settings:

Thank you by advance.

Do you use CLion Classic or Nova?
In CLion Nova the folding does not work for the files that are not a part of the project model.

I was using Nova, but after switching to classic, it works now. Thank you !

I Switched to CLion Classic, it solved the problem.
Thanks to uta.
